# Broken markdown in multiline text in chat

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat, markdown

Some features of the markdown syntax are working in multiline mode (like the quoting with `>` symbol) but most of them are not.

For example backticks:

```
`code sample;` 
this is some other text
```

or links:

```
some text here
[text](http://somelink.com)
```

Comment: See Peter Varo's response: "i guess mostly because multiline text is for codeblocks in the first place
if you want another line in chat, press Enter, and there you go ;)."

Comment: @AstroCB although I'm so used to pressing enter after each of my sentences -- I still believe it is an issue, and what I suggested is only a workaround.. However this is not limited only to backticks. Although some of the syntax is working (like quotiong)

Comment: @PeterVaro Yes- I agree that it is probably an issue; I was just giving a fair warning that it might be [meta-tag:status-bydesign].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently intentional. We only support quotes in multi-line markdown in chat.